# Jquery UI Autocomplete Different Render Item Result for Same fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have Jquery UI Autocomplete setup as follows.

```
 $(".zipcode").autocomplete({
            source:'index.php?someParams',
            minLength: 1,
            autoFocus : true,
            select : function(event, ui)
            { 
                var prefix = Some Prefix Criteria;
                var item = ui.item;
                if(item) {
                    $("#"+prefix+"_zip_id").val(item.id);
                    $("#"+prefix+"_zip").val(item.value);               
                }
            }
        }) 
        .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
              return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.state + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
        };
```

The issue is that i have two fields on page using autocomplete for zip. It renders with the renderItem changes for first Autocomplete while the data renderItem is not fired for the second autocomplete.

I also faced issues while using ID`s instead of Class like

> $("#start_zip","end_zip")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i were you, i use it like this:

```
$(".zipcode").each(function (i, el) {
    el = $(el);
    el.autocomplete({
        source:'index.php?someParams',
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus : true,
        select : function(event, ui)
        { 
            var prefix = Some Prefix Criteria;
            var item = ui.item;
            if(item) {
                $("#"+prefix+"_zip_id").val(item.id);
                $("#"+prefix+"_zip").val(item.value);               
            }
        }
    }) 
        .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.state + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
        };

});
```